# cv loading for executable

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I had imported cv2 library in my code and made an executable by using py2exe through GUI2EXE software.

Py2exe has created cv2.pyc file which is run every time the application is started and creates an error of 'Import Error: DLL load failed.Cannot find the module specified' at line mod = imp.load_dynamic(**name**,path). It has also made other files like numpy.core_sort which give the same error when run.

My question is that py2exe  is only running the cv2.pyc file while running the application. Why is it doing so? It should have just imported the cv2 library.
The code in the cv2.pyc file is given below

```
def __load():
    import imp, os, sys
    try:
        dirname = os.path.dirname(__loader__.archive)
    except NameError:
        dirname = sys.prefix
    path = os.path.join(dirname, 'cv2.pyd')
    #print "py2exe extension module", __name__, "->", path
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(__name__, path)
##    mod.frozen = 1
__load()
del __load
```

My code calls libraries in this manner :-

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons
import numpy as np
import os 
import cv2.cv as cv #Import functions from OpenCV
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image #python imaging library
```

Comment: Please post your setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Looking at cv2.cpp it has `#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"`
so it looks like it loads numpy, which is not surprising.
As `py2exe` does not see the c++ source code, it will not detect this. So I think "the module specified" that can't be found is numpy.

Adding the following line to your setup.py should fix your problem:

```
import numpy
```

Comment: The problem is that py2exe is creating other files like numpy.core_sort also which show the same error of 'Import Error: DLL load failed. The specified module could not be found' at the line mod = imp.load_dynamic(__name__,path). But on running the application those files are not run, only cv2.pyc is run. I cant understand why. My code calls libraries in this format.                                          import wx
import wx.lib.buttons
import numpy as np
import os 
import cv2.cv as cv 
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image